# Custom Login Screen for Blazor Server App using Azure AD

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, blazor, blazor-server-side, azure-ad-graph-api

I am writing an internal application using Blazor Server. So far, all I have done is create a new project using authentication and connected it a registered app in Azure that only allows users on our domain to to access. This works out of the box, when I start the application I am immediately shown the Microsoft sign in page before I can access the application. However, is there a way to allow users to hit a landing page first before choosing to login? I cant see to find a way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have a service like that being added:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

This will automatically challange the user to login if he tries to access any page of your application, so I recommend removing it.

Next, you need a login and logout button. Create it somewhere in the `MainLayout.razor`:

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        Hello, @context.User.Identity?.Name!
        <a href="MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut">Log out</a>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

Since we removed the Authorization filter from your pages, you might want to decorate your secured pages manually using this code in top of the blazor components:

```
@attribute [Authorize]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use extra Layout and which Layout use 1st time landing page, that's means where use this Layout that's page routing will be "/" or default.